# Is there a way to set the drop-down menu, via MenuPage, to the right instead of the left?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I wanted to ask if there is a way to set the drop-down menu, via MenuPage, on the right instead of on the left
This is my code:
Recall page:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MenuPage/>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Menu setting page:

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
            <d:ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Item 0</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item 4</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </d:ListView.ItemsSource>`
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Sorry Davide, I meant `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"` :)

Comment: I've been looking a little information about that. But it seems that the right way to do it is to implement custom renderers

Answer (score 0):

1. According to Juan, on the basis of using
   `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`, add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the
   **application in xxx.Android->Properties->AndroidManifest.xml**.
2. In the latest version, using Flyout is a better choice, please check
   (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage)
   for more information.